# Наличие аналога python exec в java

Tags: java, java-8, exec, eval

Есть ли в Java функция, аналогичная функции **exec** в Python? Нигде не могу найти внятного ответа - есть или нет. Если есть, то хорошо было бы ее назвать.

---

Функция exec в python "выполняет" строку, как если бы она была написана в программе как кусок кода, а не строка. Например:

```
exec("a = func()")
```

Присвоит результат функции func в переменную a

Comment: такого нет в java

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. Можете опубликовать это как ответ, если хотите. Я приму

Comment: Обсуждение соответствующей темы на англоязычной ветке
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java

Comment: Раз в java такого нет, тогда может быть поможет javascript, поддержка которого есть в жаве. Но это конечно делается не в одну строку.

Comment: Такое есть в интерпретируемых языках, в компилируемых такого не бывает. Рантайм не содержит компилятор, как правило.

Comment: На англоязычной ветке, посоветованной @Dmitry, есть неплохой аналог eval в python, но не exec. За помощь спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **java 9** появился такой инструмент как `java shell`. Для вашей задачи он вполне подходит
Пример использование можно посмотреть в [этой статье](https://dzone.com/articles/jdk9-execute-java-code-like-unix-shell-script)

Либо так в `unix` окружении:

```
String sourceCode = "1 + 2"
List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
commands.add("/bin/sh");
commands.add("-c");
commands.add("echo \"" + sourceCode + "\"" | jshell");

SystemCommandExecutor commandExecutor = new SystemCommandExecutor(commands);
int result = commandExecutor.executeCommand();

StringBuilder stdout = commandExecutor.getStandardOutputFromCommand();
StringBuilder stderr = commandExecutor.getStandardErrorFromCommand();

System.out.println("STDOUT");
System.out.println(stdout);

System.out.println("STDERR");
System.out.println(stderr);
```

Comment: В windows, как я понимаю, также, только команды несколько другие

Comment: Этот способ возвращает только результат строки(eval в python) или динамически выполняет код в контексте программы(exec в python)?

Comment: Контекст не учитывать, код выполняет отдельно @FedotSoldier

Answer (score 2):

Прямого аналога указанной функции нет, однако имеется возможность постучаться к компилятору из java-кода и скормить ему исходник, после загрузив новый класс в загрузчик классов. Ну а после можно при помощи **Reflection api** запускать методы этого класса. На англоязычной версии имеются примеры: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946338/how-do-i-programmatically-compile-and-instantiate-a-java-class) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes).

Я написал небольшую утилитку, которая компилирует и после запускает скрипт на вход которой нужно подать только сам скрипт и возвращаемый тип:

```
package ru.stackoverflow.question910353;

import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;


public class ScriptRunner {
    private static final AtomicLong COUNTER = new AtomicLong(0);
    private static File root;
    private static String packageNamePath;
    private static String packageName;
    private static File packageNameFolder;
    private static URLClassLoader classLoader;

    static {
        try {
            root = Files.createTempDirectory("dynamicClasses").toFile();
            packageName = "ru.stackoverflow.question910353";
            packageNamePath = packageName.replaceAll("\\.", "/");
            packageNameFolder = new File(root, packageNamePath);
            packageNameFolder.mkdirs();
            classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{root.toURI().toURL()});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    public static <T> T run(String script, Class<T> returnType) throws Exception {
        String className = "Test" + COUNTER.incrementAndGet();
        String source = "package " + packageName + "; public class " + className + " implements java.util.concurrent.Callable<" + returnType.getName() + "> { " +
                " public " + returnType.getName() + " call()  throws Exception  { " + script + " } }";
        File sourceFile = new File(packageNameFolder, className + ".java");
        sourceFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        Files.write(sourceFile.toPath(), source.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        compiler.run(null, null, null, sourceFile.getPath());
        Class<?> cls = Class.forName(packageName + "." + className, true, classLoader); 
        Callable<T> instance = (Callable<T>) cls.newInstance(); 
        return instance.call();
    }

}
```

И тест под неё, который доказывает работу этой утилиты:

```
package ru.stackoverflow.question910353;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class DynamicClassCompileTest {

    @Test
    public void testClassLoad() throws Exception {
        String result = ScriptRunner.run("return \"test\";", String.class);
        System.out.println("result "  + result);
        Assertions.assertEquals("test", result);

        Integer resultInt = ScriptRunner.run("" +
                "int a=5;" +
                "int b=10;" +
                "return a+b;", Integer.class);
        System.out.println("resultInt " + resultInt);
        Assertions.assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(15), resultInt);
        Assertions.assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> {
            ScriptRunner.run("invalid code",Void.class);
        });

    }


}
```

На деле же, чаще используется генерация байткода. Для этого существуют специальные библиотеки:

1. [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib)
2. [byte butty](https://bytebuddy.net/#/)

Comment: Refl_a_ction => reflection